# multiple named caches in django 1.2.7

Tags: django

how to have multiple named caches with django 1.2.7 ? There is only CACHE_BACKEND string setting. I can not update django to use the new CACHES settings. I want to have 3 named caches for 3 different sections of a django site.

Comment: Django 1.2 is four years old. There's no call to be using such an outdated version.

Comment: If Django 1.2 doesn't support what you need then you should consider upgrading. If that's not possible either then I'm not sure how we can answer your question.